# Sending data between ESP32 and computer through USB with micropython

Tags: python, esp32, uart, micropython

I have an ESP32 connected to to my computer through the usb port and have tried sending and receiving serial data. It works, but I can't make it so the ESP32 recognizes what is being sent using this code

```
from machine import Pin, PWM, UART #type: ignore
import time

uart = UART(115200)

while True:
    if uart.any():
        msg = uart.read()
        uart.write(msg)
        if msg == 'hello':
            uart.write("hello received")
```

The ESP32 should send "hello received", but it returns "hello" instead. Furthermore, this code only works when sending serial data from the arduino serial monitor. When I try running a separate python script to send "hello" and print what the ESP32 returns,

```
import serial, time

ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 115200) 

ser.write(b"hello")
time.sleep(1)
i = ser.readline()

print(i)
```

Nothing gets printed to the console. Is there a problem with my code? Thanks

Edit:
Alright I fixed my code up to include the \n and it still didn’t work. I found out using this script that I’m not sending any serial data
ESP32:

```
from machine import Pin, PWM, UART #type: ignore 
import time 
uart = UART(1,115200) 

while True: 
     print("starting") 
     msg = uart.readline() 
     print(msg) 
     time.sleep(0.01)
```

Computer:

```
import serial, time 
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 115200) 
while True: 
     ser.write(b'hello\r\n') 
     print(ser.readline()) 
     time.sleep(1)
```

The esp returns b'starting\r\n' b'None\r\n

Comment: *"The ESP32 should send "hello received", but it returns "hello" instead."* -- You're conflating what is transmitted from one end versus what is received by the other end.  To check if you're *receiving* an echo versus truncated data, use a response that is distinguishable/different from what is originally sent.  E.G. instead of `hello received`, use `RECEIVED hello`.

Comment: *"When I try running a separate python script ... Nothing gets printed to the console"* -- Looks like that the ESP32 only sends a text string, i.e. `hello received`, and the Python code is expecting to read a line, i.e. text terminated with some kind of EOL character.  IOW a text *string* is not necessarily a *line* of text.

Comment: Alright I fixed my code up to include the \n and it still didn’t work. I found out using this script that I’m not sending any serial data
ESP32:

    from machine import Pin, PWM, UART #type: ignore
    import time
    uart = UART(1,115200)
    while True: print("starting")
    msg = uart.readline()
    print(msg)
    
    time.sleep(0.01)

Computer:

    import serial, time
    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 115200) 
    while True: 
        ser.write(b'hello\r\n') 
        print(ser.readline()) 
        time.sleep(1)

The esp returns

    b'starting\r\n'
    b'None\r\n’

Comment: Don't try to explain code changes in a comment; it's incomprehensible.  Instead add this additional information to your original post using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70638229/edit) capability.

Comment: Oh right sorry about that. I've edited the post

Comment: Since your PC seems able to receive the text from the `print("starting")`  and `print(msg)` statements, there is an operational link at least in one direction.  Is your ESP32 program simply accessing the wrong UART port for this PC connection?  Seems like MicroPython doesn't have an `input()` statement to complement the `print()`.

Comment: Uart.write doesn’t work either, so I think you are right about the wrong uart port. I’ve already tried making using 1 and 2, and different baud rates, but it doesn’t work. Could it be that I need a separate usb to serial adapter?

Comment: Using an actual UART on the ESP32 (instead of the USB CDC connection) and a USB-to-TTL-serial adapter could be a reasonable path.  Having a separate communication link just for your programs that is separate from the ESP32 console should enhance debugging and operation.